# Looking at a specific line in a text document in python

Tags: python, enumerate

I have a line of code: `for line_number, line in enumerate(file):` that reads through a text file line by line, and under  that line I have an if statement that looks to see if there's a specific string in that line of the document. If it finds that string, I want the code to look at the line two lines down and look if there's a specific string in that line. The problem is, I don't know how to specify what line the code looks at, other than the first time it does it. I don't know how to take that line it found the string at, and look at a line two lines down. I want to specify a `line_number` and get the `line` for that number.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then, add the input, the expected output, and the core you tried writing to your question.

Comment: If it's a small text file then consider [reading all lines into a list](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/#iterating-over-each-line-in-the-file). Then you can easily iterate over the list.